# grails plugin for eclipse and netbeans 6.1

Tags: eclipse, grails, netbeans, plugins

Has anyone been successful in getting the grails plugin for eclipse to work? How about grails plugin with netbeans?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the NetBeans 6.5 Beta you'll see the Grails functionality is promising, but still buggy(minor).  The good thing is in 6.5 Groovy and Grails support is standard, you don't have to install the plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there hasn't been much progress on the Eclipse plugin for Grails, we have started using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for Grails development, the [JetGroovy](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/groovy_grails.html) plugin is excellent and keeps getting better!

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans 6.5 is pretty good for Grails and allows for debugging, though the code completion is just barely there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's a quick update.  The Eclipse plugin works, and has refactoring support.  But, for some reason I can't get it to recognize the Grails plugins in the Eclipse project.

It's starting to come along though.

Comment: Grails support in STS (an Eclipse Distro for working with Spring and Groovy) is becoming mature.  Are you using the Grails-Eclipse tooling?

More here:
http://www.grails.org/STS+Integration

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any problems getting the Eclipse grails plugin "to work" insofar as it's installed and providing all the features advertised. The problem is that this set of features is minimal, and light years behind IntelliJ. I understand that switching from a free IDE to a commercial IDE isn't at all possible, but if it is, do it! Although Netbeans is better than Eclipse, it's still quite a distance behind IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future documentation:
Netbeans 6.8 is available with a very nice Grails/Groovy Plugin that works like a charme.
Additionally you can use a new Code Coverage Plugin.
Really nice build.

Link:
[Netbeans Homepage](http://netbeans.org/)

But you have to keep in mind that Grails now belongs to Spring Source. Spring Source is known for developing their own Tool Suite based on Eclipse. Maybe we will see a better grails plugin implementation for Eclipse.